# Two Different window.open(location) in different if blocks going to the same destination

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, if-statement, window.open

I am writing a school project and the code works like this.

1. It shows suggestions to the user to select and the data are stored with specific values as the checkboxes.
2. The jQuery and js code check the checked boxes and the respective values are stored in respective variable.
3. Compare the varibles and then the one genre that is chosen the most will lead to the next page using "window.open('location','target');"

---

**Here comes the problem. **


The code works perfectly fine as for the first "if block". It lead directly to the "comedy_movie_suggestion"page.

When it comes to the second "else if" part (tried with "if" alone too; no difference), the code is leading me to the "comedy_movie_suggestion" page still.

//It leads to the correct pages if I give in the webpages from Google (the url) but the point is it is not taking me to the "drama_movie_suggestion" page.

//The filename is correct and yes, they are in the same folder.

P.S: I also put my html and css codes, for the ease of you to test it out.

Please feel free to clarify anything if you have any.

Thank you.

---

Here are my codes (Html and js are in the same file since I am checking for only one logic)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
        <title> Crux - Your missing piece</title>
    
        <!--logo on tab title-->
        <link rel="icon" href="images/logo.png" type="image/png"/>
        
        <!--link to Css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style_movie_suggestion.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <header> 
            <img id="logo" src="images/logo+name.png" alt="Crux">
        </header>
        
        <div id="intro">
            <p> <br> &emsp; &emsp; &emsp;Please tick the checkbox for the movies you like. After your submission, we will take you to one of the treasure boxes which will contain <em><strong>Crux's top  5 movies list for you.</strong></em> When you get there... click on the movie poster of the one you would like to watch!</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="parent"> 
            <ul id="learn"> 
                
                <!--Guardian of the Galaxy-->
                <li>
                    <input id="guardian" type="checkbox" class="comedy">
                    <label for="guardian" ><img src="images/learn/guardian.jpg" alt="Guardian Of the Galaxies poster here"></label>
                    <br>
                </li>
                
                <!--The Bird Box-->
                <li>
                    <input id="bird_box" type="checkbox" class="drama">
                    <label for="bird_box"><img src="images/learn/birdbox.jpg" alt="The Bird Box poster here."> </label>
                </li>
                <!--Love and Monster-->
                <li> 
                    <input id="love" type="checkbox" class="comedy">
                    <label for="love"> <img src="images/learn/loveAndMonster.jpg" alt="Love and Monsters poster here."></label>
                </li>
                
                <!--Death On the Nile-->
                <li> 
                    <input id="nile" type="checkbox" class="comedy">
                    <label for="nile"> <img src="images/learn/deathOnTheNile.jpg" alt="Death on the Nile poster here."> </label>
                </li>

                <!--The King-->
                <li> 
                    <input id="theKing" type="checkbox" class="drama">
                    <label for="theKing"> <img src="images/learn/TheKing.jpg"> </label>
                </li>
                
                <!--guardian--> 
                <li> 
                    <input id="army" type="checkbox" class="comedy">
                    <label for="army"> <img src="images/learn/armyOfThieves.jpg" alt="Army of Thieves poster here."></label>
                </li>
                
                <!--The Everest-->
                <li>
                    <input id="everest" type="checkbox" class="drama">
                    <label for="everest"> <img src="images/learn/everest.jpg" alt="The Everest poster here."></label>
                </li>

                <!--Shazam-->
                <li> 
                    <input id="shazam" type="checkbox" class="comedy">
                    <label for="shazam"> <img src="images/learn/shazam.jpg" alt="Shazam poster here."></label>
                </li>
                
                <!--Suicide Squad-->
                <li> 
                    <input id="squad" type="checkbox" class="comedy">
                    <label for="squad"> <img src="images/learn/suicide.jpg" alt="Suicide Squad poster here."></label>
                </li>

                <!--The Good Nurse-->
                <li>
                    <input id="GoodNurse" type="checkbox" class="drama">
                    <label for="GoodNurse"> <img src="images/learn/GoodNurse.jpg"> </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div id="for_button">
            <button id="bt1">Continue</button>
        </div>
        
    <!--Link to jQuery-->
    <script 
    type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">
    </script>
        

    <script> 
        
        $(function(){
            
            $("#bt1").click(function(){
                var comedy = ($("#parent .comedy:checkbox:checked").length);
                
                var drama = ($("#parent .drama:checkbox:checked").length);
                                
                var romance = ($("#parent .romance:checkbox:checked").length); 
            
                
                if (comedy>drama && comedy>romance){
                     window.open('comedy_suggestion.html','_blank');
                }
                  
                else if (drama>comedy && drama>romance){
                        window.alert("You love drama movies.");
                        window.open("drama_suggestion.html",'_blank');
                }
                
                else if (romance>comedy && romance>drama){
                    alert("you love romance movies");
                }
                
                else if (comedy==drama && comedy>romance){
                    alert("You love both comedy and drama");
                }
                
                else if(drama==romance && drama>comedy){
                    alert("You love both drama and romance");
                }
                
                else if (comedy==romance && comedy>drama){
                    alert("You love both comedy and romance");
                }
                else if (drama==comedy && comedy==romance && drama!=0 && comedy!=0 && romance!=0){
                    alert("You love all geners of movies equally");
                }
                
                else{
                    alert("choose at least one movie");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    
    <!--icons installation-->
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Css Here

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document for Styling Comedy movies suggestions page */
body{
        backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
        background-color: black;
        color: #d4af37;
        font-family: Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", "serif";
    }

    #nav{
        list-style-type: none;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
/*for img as a checkbox*/
#learn {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 5vh;
    text-align: center;
}

#learn li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]{
    display: none;
}

label {
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
     user-select: none;

}

label::before {
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 28px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transform: scale(0);
}

label img {
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}


:checked+label::before {
  content: "✓";
  background-color: #d4af37;
  transform: scale(1);
}

:checked+label img {
  transform: scale(0.9);
  z-index: -1;
}
    
    nav a{
        color: #d4af37;
        text-decoration: none;  
        margin-right: 4.5em;
        font-size: 17pt;
    }
    
    a:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
        margin-right: 4em;
        transition:all 0.3s linear 0s;
      }
     
      a:hover:after {
        width: 65%;
      }
    header{
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    p{
        text-align: justify;
        margin: 0 17px 0 17px;
    }
    

    .display_suggestion{
        margin-left: 2em;
        margin-right: 3em;
        width: 95%;
        text-align: center;
        display: flex;
    }
    
    .movies{
        margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    }
    
    img{
        width: 14em;
        height: 23em;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

#logo{
    width: 19em;
    height: 5em;
}

#for_button{
    text-align: center;
}

#bt1{
    height: 3em;
    width: 9em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color:black;
    background-color: #d4af37;
}

    @media screen and (max-width:1500px) {  
        .display_suggestion{
            margin-left: 3em;
            margin-right: 3em;
            width: 95%;
            text-align: center;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        
        nav a{
            margin-right: 2em;
        }
    }
```

//It leads to the correct pages if I give in the webpages from Google (the url) but the point is it is not taking me to the "drama_movie_suggestion" page.

//The filename is correct and yes, they are in the same folder.

**I want it to lead to the correct pages.**

Comment: Have you tried console.log the values of comedy, romance and drama variables just before your if/else if condition?  If so, what are the values of those variables when you expect the logic to take you to the drama page?

Comment: If I have clicked three input boxes of value=drama, it shows 3 for (var) drama. It shows how many number of boxes I have ticked. So my logic is I compare those things and let say the highest number is 3;can be varied (drama) then it should take to the drama movie suggestion page.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your results.  I loaded your HTML and JS into [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/ag7432bm/), checked 3 drama checkboxes, and I get the drama alert as well as an attempt to load https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/drama_suggestion.html in a new tab.

Comment: I am so sorry but I am not advanced enough to understand the “an attempt to load https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/drama_suggestion.html in a new tab” meaning. Could you please enlighten me? I am just a student and new to js.

Comment: What I mean:  I set up an example of your code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/ag7432bm/).  I clicked several drama options. I then saw the drama alert.  And then it attempted to open the drama_suggestion.html page (which of course is not found because it's not your server).  So, I can't reproduce your issue.  There must be something else going on that isn't reflected in the code you posted if you are not getting drama_suggestion.html when you select 3 drama checkboxes.

Comment: That is super weird because that’s all the code I have those are related to it. My drama_suggestion has nothing other than normal Html structure and “this is the drama page” line in the body. Sometimes it shows can’t get blah blah blah when I wrote the wrong name with other pages during assignments. This time it is correct but just took me to the comedy page. Is there any chances that the first “if” block is interfering this drama one?

Comment: Omg! My recklessness I deleted the wrong file last night and this drama page has the code pasted from the comedy page. I am so sorry! Thank you so much for finding it out for me.